# Catch-up missed messages

Tags: mqtt

As far as my understanding goes, when a message is published to a topic, it is received by only the clients currently subscribed to that topic. If a client turns up after the message is published, it won't receive that message.

Suppose a client is disconnected momentarily, is there a way to help the client catch-up with the messages missed when it is connected again?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If a client subscribes to a topic then the connection to the broker is dropped, the client will need to reconnect.

As long as client sets the cleanSession=false flag on the connection and resubscribes to the same topics the broker should replay any missed messages.

A more detailed description of durable subscriptions can be found here:

http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/

and here:

http://www.thingsprime.com/?p=2897

Comment: The Thingsprime Link is a bit outdated, since all three mentioned brokers nowadays support queued messages correctly. Still a useful resource, though

Comment: Follow up answer, proposed solution and request for feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229861/mqtt-catch-up-missed-messages-looking-for-feedback-on-design-assumptions