# MQTT catch-up missed messages, looking for feedback on design/assumptions

Tags: mqtt

I would like some feedback on this problem and my proposed solution to catching up after missed MQTT messages please:

---

**[Update 1]** Simplified problem diagram and added solution diagram. Added mention of QoS

---

**Scenario:**

Client A publishes messages that we wish Client B to receive, even if connections are temporarily dropped then restored.

**Config**

- Client A: connect with clean=false. Publish stateful messages with retain = true, non-stateful messages published with retain = false
- Client B: connect with clean=false

[image]

**What will happen**

Each time Client A publishes to topic "foo", previous messages are **replaced** on the broker. Ex. Client A publishes `111`, `222`, `333`. Client B connects after the messages are published. Client B will receive only, `333`. Thus, messages `111` and `222` were missed because each message replaced the previous one on that same topic (different topics do not replace each other).

**Proposed solution**

I envision two types of messages. Stateful and non-stateful. Stateful messages would be things like, voltage, temperature, gps location, pressure. Non-stateful messages would be things like a chat message where history is more likely to be important for context. Missed stateful messages are more likely to be tolerable while non-stateful messages might not be tolerable.

All messages are published with QoS 1 in my case.

For the stateful messages I am thinking Client A will publish with retain = true.

For the non-stateful messages, I am thinking Client A will publish with retain = false (because what good is the last message if we don't have the full historical context of previous messages). When Client B connects/reconnects, I will publish a catch-up (arbitrary name) message containing all the ids of the messages it received, which when Client A receives it, will respond by publishing the whole history of messages minus those in the id list (ids maintained in Client A db). This might work for me if the total aggregate message history isn't too big.

[image]

The alternative might be for Client B to send read receipts for each message received.

For me, these two solutions will require a database of messages and some custom logic

---

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953138/catch-up-missed-messages) which I tried answering but was asked to instead form it as an independent, follow-up question.

Comment: You've not mentioned what QOS that messages are published at

Comment: @hardillb updated to mention all messages published with QoS 1 and added diagram of proposed catch-up solution, thanks!

Comment: An alternative is to make the non-stateful also retain=true. That way the broker sends the last message on subscriber reconnect, and the Client:Webserver can decide whether it needs to catch up. This shifts some burden from the clients to the broker.

Comment: Sorry, I should have also asked what QOS the subscriptions are made at as well (I'll assume they are QOS 1 as well) as that is more important for ensuring queued delivery to offline clients

Comment: Yes, QoS 1 for subscribers and good thinking on the retain true for non-stateful because that's one less message to catch up on. Thank you